# Disqus SSO working intermittently - sometimes shows 404 error

Tags: php, single-sign-on, disqus

The Disqus SSO actually works great for me, but the problem is that it is working only intermittently. Sometimes the user is logged in, and the Disqus comment box works fine, but other times, it doesn't log my user in..it is pretty much ignoring the code below, or that is not working correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var disqus_config = function() {
    this.page.remote_auth_s3 = "<?php echo "$message $hmac $timestamp"; ?>";
    this.page.api_key = "<?php echo DISQUS_PUBLIC_KEY; ?>";
}
</script>
```

I'm sure I have everything configured correctly, having used this below my disqus comment box:

https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/blob/master/sso/php/sso.php

The error I get in the Chrome console when my user is not automatically authenticated in the Disqus comment box is below:

```
> http://disqus.com/api/3.0/embed/threadDetails.json?thread=___…1&api_key=___404 (NOT FOUND) lib.js:162 send lib.js:162 e.extend.ajax lib.js:157 d

> client.js:27 g.call client.js:28 u.extend.fetch client.js:85
> Backbone.View.extend.fetchSession client.js:122
> Backbone.View.extend.initSession client.js:118
> Backbone.View.extend.bootstrap client.js:113 w lib.js:216
> n.Events.trigger lib.js:215 messageHandler
```

However, when this error does show, and I refresh the page, oftentimes, it goes away and the user is authenticated. Really not sure what it can be. I've tried moving the javascript for the sso around, such as putting it into the document head, but I'm getting nowhere now.

I'm sure I have everything configured correctly, having used this below my disqus comment box:

[Disqus php api example](https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/blob/master/sso/php/sso.php)

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the full request, but this might be a better question for support: http://disqus.com/support/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I left the whole thing alone...the problem went away. If you have this same problem, don't waste your time trying to fix it, give it a day or 2 first

Comment: Same exact issue here. I gave it two days! I emailed Support. The domain and application took time to replicate on their side, I'm guessing.

Comment: 5 years later 

Comment: lol, yeah. replication probably. I've got my implementation working well now.